XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 8, column 16
получаю вот такой ответ от soap запроса:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SearchRecordsByReportResponse xmlns="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/">
            <SearchRecordsByReportResult>
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                <Records count="1">
                    <Metadata>
                        <FieldDefinitions>
                            <FieldDefinition id="21973" guid="8f1d12ca-9a2a-463c-bc57-bb4f59aea5ef" name="Идентификатор" alias="Идентификатор" />
                            <FieldDefinition id="22024" guid="8c4790ef-371e-40f4-9989-2bee634a9bdb" name="Наименование" alias="Наименование" />
                            <FieldDefinition id="22033" guid="35d493a3-a117-4d80-961d-bb72f022c7c6" name="Наличие" alias="Наличие" />
                        </FieldDefinitions>
                    </Metadata>
                    <LevelCounts>
                        <LevelCount id="329" guid="ade1d387-af1a-4642-9bbf-719f9b3ab251" count="1" />
                    </LevelCounts>
                    <Record contentId="253165" levelId="329" levelGuid="ade1d387-af1a-4642-9bbf-719f9b3ab251" moduleId="531" parentId="0">
                        <Field id="22024" guid="8f1d12ca-9a2a-463c-bc57-bb4f59aea5ef" type="12">Name1</Field>
                        <Field id="21973" guid="8c4790ef-371e-40f4-9989-2bee634a9bdb" type="16">253165</Field>
                        <Field id="22033" guid="35d493a3-a117-4d80-961d-bb72f022c7c6" type="34">
                            <ListValues>
                                <ListValue id="83811" displayName="Да">Да</ListValue>
                            </ListValues>
                        </Field>
                    </Record>
                </Records>
            </SearchRecordsByReportResult>
        </SearchRecordsByReportResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

При попытке парсинга, например так:
response = requests.post(**param['request'])
doc = xmltodict.parse(response.text)

падает ошибка: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 8, column 16
Т.е. виновата строка 8 где объявляется декларация.
Как правильно с этим SOAP работать? не вырезать же мне её

А по-другому наверное никак. Это некорректный XML, насколько я понимаю. Только вырезать лишний заголовок из текста. Это не сложно, одно списковое включение, и всё.
